# What are the specifics of "allocated" in a PHP out of memory error

Tags: php, memory

Note: There are a number of questions dealing with the "out of memory" error message, but I haven't seen an answer to the specifics of the "allocated" definition.

In any stat, you have to know what is being measured. What does "allocated" measure specifically?

My client's hosting package supposedly has 256MB of PHP memory, based on the php.ini setting. The webhost does allow up to 256MB.

Example: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 118489088) (tried to allocate 64
bytes) in
/htdocs/www/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/vendor/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
on line 293

Does allocated mean the memory for all PHP functions or just for the particular process that is throwing the error?

Comment: PHP is a single process, unless you're working with [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) (multi-threading), which I highly doubt is your case. So `Out of memory` means it's either out of memory allocated to PHP inside the `php.ini` file or your webservers (apache most likely) allocated memory set with the [LimitRequestBody Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody), although its set to "unlimited" by default.

Comment: @icecub Not only `pthreads`, but [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) as well.

Comment: @BVengerov True, but since it's a comment I reduced it to one example.

Comment: This site is in a Debian 6 environment. Does that make a difference? Of course, it's super old and I'm hoping the owner will agree to have it moved.

Answer (score 0):

The comment about PHP being one process was very helpful in finding an answer to this question. The confusing issue is that each new process load should have its own memory space. It turns out that PHP has a memory manager within itself that allocates memory to the individual processes on the site. The memory available to PHP is the amount the PHP memory manager has to work with.

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.php